# Equivalent message properties in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to centralize all my String in a single file to reuse them everywhere in an app in flutter.
Does it exist an "message properties" java way equivalent in dart ? And how can I reuse them anywhere in my app?

Thank you

Comment: just create a file `"app_strings.dart"` or whatever and place all strings there like `const hello_world= "Hello world";`. Then you can use them thoughout the app. Make sure to import the file

Comment: Oh yes, simply... Thank you, that was a so stupid question, looking for something more complicated

Comment: I would not say the question is stupid. If you e.g. want to support multiple languages you will end up wanting another solution than just a file defining String constants.

Comment: yes for multiple languages you'll  need i18n like packages